# fill array key value from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting 2 arrays from that code :

```
$default = '2000,1000,750';
$defaultRule = 'min-width:2000,min-width:1000,min-width:750';
$arr_responsive = explode(',' , $default);
$arr_responsiveRule = explode(',' , $defaultRule);
```

now I want to get an unique array with keys = $arr_responsive , values =  $arr_responsiveRule

to get :

```
$array(
    '2000'  => 'min-width:2000',
    '1000'  => 'min-width:1000',
    '750'  => 'min-width:750'
)
```

thanks for helping

Comment: it works ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_combine(
    $arr_responsive,     // these are keys
    $arr_responsiveRule  // these are values
)
```